# I can not import from csv files into Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

```sql
// BadgesNode
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Badges.csv' AS row
CREATE (:Badges {
  classid: toInteger(row.Class),
  name: row.Name,
  badgeId: toInteger(row.Id)
})
WITH *
LIMIT 1
RETURN classid, name, badgeId;
```

when I run it, there is no value in the properties. But when I run this cypher

```sql
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Badges.csv' AS row
RETURN row
```

and this is the result that it returns:

```json
{
  "Name": "Informed",
  "Date": "2014-05-13 23:06",
  "Class": "3",
  "Id": "1",
  "UserId": "1",
  "TagBased": "FALSE"
}
```

I can not understand why the first cypher does not return values into the properties. Can somebody help me. I stuck in this part for two days.

I need to fill the properties by the values in the csv file.
And this is a subset of my csv file.

[image]

Comment: The data shown in the attached image doesn't match the query. Mistake?

Answer (score 0):

With the first query, you are probably getting an error telling you that `classId` is not defined. In which case, no nodes are being created.

If you are just looking to test the properties of the first created node, you can modify your existing query to declare a variable e.g. `n` in the node pattern. You can then access node properties with the dot notation in the `RETURN` clause:

```sql
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Badges.csv' AS row
CREATE (n:Badges {
  classid: toInteger(row.Class),
  name: row.Name,
  badgeId: toInteger(row.Id)
})
RETURN n.classid, n.name, n.badgeId 
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you it return the values but here again there is no value in the Badge node in the properties.
{
  "identity": 0,
  "labels": [
    "Badges"
  ],
  "properties": {

  },
  "elementId": "0"
}

Comment: What exact query returns `{ "identity": 0, "labels": [ "Badges" ], "properties": { }, "elementId": "0" }` ?

Comment: when I use this cypher "MATCH (n:Badges) RETURN n LIMIT 25" it shows nothing in the properties! :(
{
  "identity": 0,
  "labels": [
    "Badges"
  ],
  "properties": {

  },
  "elementId": "0"
}
but when I use this cypher "//BadgeNodeImport
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Badges.csv' AS row
CREATE (n:Badges {
  classid: toInteger(row.Class),
  name: row.Name,
  badgeId: toInteger(row.Id)
})
RETURN n.classid, n.name, n.badgeId 
LIMIT 1000;" it returns a table that has all the values that I need.
like :

Comment: Can I have your email address to show you the exact result that I need but it does not work !

Comment: It seems you are looking at the Table results view in Neo4j Browser. Perhaps the first Badges nodes created were from an earlier unsuccessful attempt. Try running `MATCH (n:Badges) WHERE NOT n.classid IS NULL RETURN n LIMIT 25`. Alternatively, your Badges.csv file does not have the columns you expect. I say that because the image you attached did not match your query.